# Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND '0' when trying to start nuxt dev server

Tags: dns, nuxt.js

I wanted to start a nuxt dev server with this script in my `package.json` (my goal is to access the page from my mobile phone to test it):

```json
"dev:host": "nuxt --hostname '0' --port 8000"
```

I basically copied the line from the nuxt docs (https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/configuration#edit-host-and-port), but I get this error when executing the script:

```
FATAL  getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND '0'
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:64:26)
```

That's weird, because when I edit `nuxt.config.js` and add a server object with the same properties, it works (at least at my pc, i still can't access the page with my phone although its in the same network, but I guess that's a different problem). Has anyone stumbled across this dns.js error as well?

Comment: @kissu Hey, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I get the same error with your nuxt app. My version is 2.15.4, too. So I guess the error is system related.

Comment: Share a repo for me to test it locally!

Comment: do you any updates for this? im also experiencing this problem now,.

Comment: @AbingPj nope, still got the same error. i guess it is system related, but i have no clue why

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Replace '0' with 0.0.0.0 (no quotes). It works for me on Windows 11.

```json
"dev:host": "nuxt --hostname 0.0.0.0 --port 80"
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure of the issue here since it's working totally fine on my side.

Maybe try with `0.0.0.0`.

Also, what is your OS? It's maybe your `@nuxt/cli` version?

Here is my test repo: https://github.com/kissu/so-nuxt-vimeo

Maybe host one on github and share it to me, that way I may try and see if it's fine on my side or not (will help debugging if it's Nuxt or system related).

[image]